# Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm trying to implement a login page using the django login view, here is the code :

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
)
```

and the template:

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'base_cost_control.html' %}
{% block contentbase %}

{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Invalid user or password</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row" align="center">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3> CONTROL DE COSTOS </h3>
    <br><br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width=700px>{%include "partials/field.html" with field=form.username %}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=700px>{%include "partials/field.html" with field=form.password %}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><input type="submit"  class="btn btn-info" name = "siguiente" id="siguiente"          value="Ingresar"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

</form>

{% endblock contentbase %}
```

So, I know django.contrib,auth.views.login generates the view and I only have to create the login.html template, but I get this error at line 8 in login.html:

```
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I don know what else to do...

Answer (score 11):

You haven't named the login url, so you can't reverse it by the name `login`. Just add the name to the pattern:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: Thanx for answering me, did what you told me but now it doesnt recognize the django login view, same line marked in login.html and this error:  Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: As well as changing `urlpatterns`, you should change the url tag to use the name: `{% url 'login' %}`.